# Java SIGSEGV error when running from docker

Tags: java, linux, docker, segmentation-fault

I have no experience in Java and I can run my code successfully from the development. But only when I built the project and runs it from docker, I got an error like this.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000000200a6, pid=1, tid=0x00007ff7227f9b10
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.12.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Sat May  4 17:33:35 UTC 2019)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000000200a6
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/my_project/hs_err_pid1.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

I have followed the error message to use `ulimit -c unlimited` by adding it in the docker command: `docker run --ulimit core=-1 --env-file -t my_project` but still not helping and got another similar error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000000200a6, pid=1, tid=0x00007eff79c95b10
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.12.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Sat May  4 17:33:35 UTC 2019)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000000200a6
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/my_project/core or core.1
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/my_project/hs_err_pid1.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ADD ./build/libs/ /opt/my_project
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat && ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
WORKDIR /opt/my_project
CMD ["java", "-jar", "my_project.jar"]
```

I have no idea if the error is related to the java environment or the docker or something else. Appreciate the help!

EDIT:

The error occurred when running on this line:

```java
Logging logging = LoggingOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(googleCredentials).setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
```

Comment: Does using an Ubuntu-based image work better?  The Dockerfile you attached is almost a minimal "run a prebuilt jar file in Docker" image; are there are more details on how to reproduce the issue you can share?

Comment: @DavidMaze updated the question with the code where the error occurred. Do you have any suggestions what docker base image I can use?

Comment: `openjdk:8-jre-slim-buster` will be based on Debian instead of Alpine, which has a different library stack that might work better.

Comment: The google logging library depends on the conscrypt library, which has a few binary dependencies (it ships a native library), which is not compatible with alpine. the debian based jdk will probably work better than an alpine one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is solved by using the debian based image instead of alpine.

Thanks to the folks in the comment section!

Comment: I used this,

    ARG VERSION=bullseye-slim

    FROM debian:${VERSION}

Answer (score 3):

Just documenting our own experience here, which corroborates rahmathd's answer.

We were using an alpine-based Amazon Corretto:

```
FROM amazoncorretto/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jre

RUN apk --update --no-cache add tzdata && apk add --no-cache libstdc++ && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat && ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo
```

One of the following two messages accompanied the crash that happened every time when running the app for a couple of seconds.

**1)**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbd3196c5d6, pid=1, tid=60
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (11.0.8+10) (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-musl-x86_64.so.1+0x235d6]  free+0x28
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: //core
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1.log
[thread 301 also had an error]
[thread 37 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**2)**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Switching to either a Ubuntu and Amazon Linux based Corretto both solved the issue for us as well.